# Alpha to Colour Value in GIMP

Tags: color, gimp, transparency

I can convert from colour to alpha, but I need to convert from alpha to color.

I have created an image containing only white text and I want to convert the semi-transparent pixels (the text smoothing) to different values of white (0-254, 0 being black, 255 being white which is the text color) and then export it to a 8-bit raw image data.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Add a layer below and fill it with black
2. Paint directly on the text layer (bucket-fill or else) with the paint tool in `Behind` mode.

[image]

Comment: I was waay over the board, hah. Do you happen to know if GIMP can export to it to a 8 bit raw pixel data now?

Comment: `File > Export` and in the file selector at the bottom pick "Raw image data". And cross fingers, because "raw" is not that well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to remove the "alpha channel".
On GIMP 2.8.22 (linux) this can be done via the menu
"Layer/Transparency/Remove Alpha Channel"
which will replace the alpha channel with the background color